# Conditionally change the image field style and wrapping it in a div

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks, media, entities

The Article content type has been classified by taxonomy vocab Topic, where each Article's node has one topic.

For some usability and design requirements, I want Articles belongs to a specific topic to render the image field in different image style when it is on the `full` display mode.

I used the code in `node--article.tpl.php`:

```
if ($node->field_topic['und'][0]['tid'] == 154){
     // In some preprocessor...
    $images = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
    if(!empty($images)) {
      $image = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_image', $images[0], array(
        'type' => 'image',
        'settings' => array(
          'image_style' => '200x260',
          'attributes' => array('class'=>'center-text')
        )
      ));
    }
    // Testing wrapping the image
    $variables['image'] = "----".$image."----";

    // Now, in your .tpl.php
     $content['field_image'] =  $image;
     }  
  print render($content)
```

The above code renders the image with HTML code like the following:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://example.com/path/to/image/10_0.jpg?itok=COlIqejP" width="200" height="260">
```

However, it works fine but has two limitations:

1- I could not able to figure out how to enclose  the image inside a `div` with css class to style it using CSS. The img tag is supplied only i.e without any wrapping divs or spans!

2- Using it from `node--article.tpl.php` is not recommended and I have a custom module, but I don't know the suitable node's hook that allows me to perform this task.

Comment: so the `center-text` div class does not get printed?

Answer (score 1):

You can set wrapper for it with simple way
instead

`print render($content);`

just use

`print '<div class="my-wrapper">'.render($content['field_image']).'</div>`;

and for second limitation if you have not `$node` just need load it with `node_load`  ( if you have nid)

So before your code

```
  $node= node_load($nid);
```

Comment: `render($content)` prints out all node's contents, so this wrapper will not be dedicated for the image only!

Comment: @sємsєм I update my answer

Comment: Note that in node--article.tpl.php you should then `hide($content['field_image']);` so that it does not render twice if also using `render($content);`.

Comment: no first `render($content['field_image'])` then `hide($content['field_image']);` then `render($content);`, ok?